# How to remove line if variable is empty

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am currently learning how to print a textarea with data inside, but am having trouble trying to think of a way to remove lines which have empty values

```
    String color1 = "";
    String color2 = "";
    String color3 = "";
    String color4 = "";
    String color5 = "";
    String color6 = "";
    String color7 = "";
    String color8 = "";
    int weight1 = 0;
    int weight2 = 0;
    int weight3 = 0;
    int weight4 = 0;
    int weight5 = 0;
    int weight6 = 0;
    int weight7 = 0;
    int weight8 = 0;


    TextArea.setText("COLOR\t\t:\t WEIGHT:" + 
            "\n=====================================\n" +
            color1 +"\t\t\t "+ weight1 + "\n" +
            color2 +"\t\t\t "+ weight2 + "\n" +
            color3 +"\t\t\t "+ weight3 + "\n" +
            color4 +"\t\t\t "+ weight4 + "\n" +
            color5 +"\t\t\t "+ weight5 + "\n" +
            color6 +"\t\t\t "+ weight6 + "\n" +
            color7 +"\t\t\t "+ weight7 + "\n" +
            color8 +"\t\t\t "+ weight8 );
}
```

Usually, only color1 & color2 with their weights have a value, very rarely does it reach color8. Although color8 & its weight does not have a value how can I make sure it is not displayed in the textarea only if it has a value?

Comment: first of all use arrays (and avoid color1...8) and if color and weight are related one to the other then maybe it is an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can store colors and weights in a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) but only insert the values that have a weight assigned. You can then convert entries into a `String`:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("white", 2);
map.put("red", 1);

String text = map.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .map(e -> e.getKey() + "\t\t\t " + e.getValue() + "\n")
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: then you cannot repeat colours as you are using them as a key.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you should have an array of values and use a method like the following where you check if there exists a color, if yes then add to the output.

```
int index=0;
StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
while(index<colors.length && Strings.isNotEmpty(colors[index]){
   result.append(colors[index]);
   result.append(DELIMITER); // \t\t\t 
   result.append(weights[index]);
   result.append("\n");
}
return result;
```

Comment: You probably want to increment the `index` somewhere, currently it stays at `0`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use arrays for the colors, you can check if each color is an empty string:

```
TextArea.setText("COLOR\t\t:\t WEIGHT:" + 
            "\n=====================================\n" +
            !color1.equals("")?color1 +"\t\t\t "+ weight1 + "\n" +:"";
            !color2.equals("")?color2 +"\t\t\t "+ weight2 + "\n" +:"";
            !color3.equals("")?color3 +"\t\t\t "+ weight3 + "\n" +:"";
            !color4.equals("")?color4 +"\t\t\t "+ weight4 + "\n" +:"";
            !color5.equals("")?color5 +"\t\t\t "+ weight5 + "\n" +:"";
            !color6.equals("")?color6 +"\t\t\t "+ weight6 + "\n" +:"";
            !color7.equals("")?color7 +"\t\t\t "+ weight7 + "\n" +:"";
            !color8.equals("")?color8 +"\t\t\t "+ weight8:""; );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String color1 = "";
            String color2 = "";
            String color3 = "";
            String color4 = "";
            String color5 = "";
            String color6 = "";
            String color7 = "";
            String color8 = "";
            int weight1 = 0;
            int weight2 = 0;
            int weight3 = 0;
            int weight4 = 0;
            int weight5 = 0;
            int weight6 = 0;
            int weight7 = 0;
            int weight8 = 0;

            List<String> colors= Arrays.asList(color1, color2 , color3 , color4 , color5 , color6 , color7 , color8);
            List<String> colors2=  colors.stream().filter(p -> colors.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<Integer> weights = Arrays.asList(weight1, weight2, weight3, weight4, weight5, weight6, weight7, weight8);

            stamp(colors2,weights);

    }

   private static void  stamp (List<String> colors, List<Integer> weights) {


       String header ="COLOR\t\t:\t WEIGHT:" + 
            "\n=====================================\n";

       String row = "";
       int i = 0;
       for (String color : colors) {
           row = row + color +"\t\t\t "+ weights.get(i)+ "\n";
           i++;
       }
        System.out.println(header+row);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> weights = new ArrayList<>();

String text = "COLOR\t\t:\t WEIGHT:" + 
          "\n=====================================";
if (!colors.isEmpty() && !weights.isEmpty()) {
  for (String color : colors) {
      if (weights.get(colors.indexOf(color) != null) {
         text = text + "\n" + color +"\t\t\t "+ weights.get(colors.indexOf(color));
      }
  }
}

TextArea.setText(text);
```